# How can I create a SwiftUI list with separated members, without using Section

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

How can I, without using `Section`, achieve a list that looks like this:

[List with separated members](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGtwD.png) --> This list has separated members

[List with no separation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsI0C.png) --> This list has no separated members

Here is how the list is created, using `Section`:

```
List {
    ForEach(item, id: \.self) { item in
        Section {
            NavigationLink {
                VStack {
                    Text(name ?? "Err").font(.title)
                    Text(category ?? "Err").font(.subheadline)
                }
            } label: {
                HStack {
                    Text("\(order)")
                    Spacer()
                    Text(name ?? "Err")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
.listStyle(.insetGrouped)
```

Comment: What's wrong with using `Section`?

Comment: I don't understand your goal here. You either using Section or Something Else requires more code. Also, if you want more customizable just go with ForEach{} + HStack like this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66222068/how-to-create-list-row-seperate-one-another-in-swiftui

Comment: @DávidPásztor it's extremely choppy/laggy looking when editing the list, moving items up and down on the list

Comment: ForEach and padding

Comment: @tail I am looking for a solution that doesn't require me to implement the maneuverability that SwiftUI lists have built in

Comment: @Cora this doesn't allow there to be a break between list Items. I need the background color to be seen between each item

Comment: @elixir I would recommend using `ForEach` plus `HStack` instead.

Comment: @tail does that require me to implement list maneuverability from scratch? (dragging and dropping, delete button, etc)

Comment: Yes you are required. Swiftui List is very limited in term of design customization, so that’s your only choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution for this is to turn off default row background and separators and make row drawing by ourselves using row insets to manage distances between rows... and this will not break default List bahavior.

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[image: demo]

```
List {
    ForEach([1, 2, 3], id: \.self) { item in
        NavigationLink {
            VStack {
                Text("name \(item)").font(.title)
            }
        } label: {
            HStack {
                Text("\(item)")
                Spacer()
                Text("name \(item)").font(.title)
            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
    .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12).fill(.red))
    .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
    .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
    .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 4, leading: 0, bottom: 4, trailing: 0))
}
.listStyle(.insetGrouped)
```

Comment: Thank you this is a fantastic answer! I wish I had enough reputation to upvote :)

Comment: This is a great answer I agreed. Btw @joker you can click "correct answer" without any required reputation.