# How to show UITableView in view?

Tags: swiftui

I'm new to SwiftUI and I want to show UITableView in my MainScreen view's body.

I made a UIViewController class and UITableView in that completely but I don't know how to add it in my MainScreen view's body. I get this error:

> Static method 'buildExpression' requires that 'UITableView' conform to 'View'

Comment: instead of asking question need to read some documents regarding SwiftUI https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui

Comment: What is the reason not to use native SwiftUI `List/ForEach`?

Comment: @vadian I Want Custom Cells

Comment: SwiftUI cells (aka `View`s) are more (and easier) customizable than `UITableViewCell`. Anyway to use any `UIViewController` in SwiftUI you need `UIViewControllerRepresentable`

Comment: @vadian You mean Like This? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66222068/how-to-create-list-row-seperate-one-another-in-swiftui

Answer (score 0):

You can use `List` as `UITableView`. Here is the sample code:

```
struct CustomListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach (0...10,id:\.self){_ in 
                CustomCell()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Custom Cell

```
struct CustomCell:View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
    }
}
```

Design your custom cell according your requirement.